# Difference of 2 Ways of Adding Elements to Java ArrayList Using Iterator

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the difference between:

```
for (ArrayList<Integer> a : result)
    temp.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(a));
```

and

```
for (ArrayList<Integer> a : result)
    temp.add(a);
```

?

Answer (score 1):

`new ArrayList(a)` actually copies the Arraylist that you already have, see the [javadoc of the constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection))

So when you have

```
ArrayList A = new Arraylist();
//fill the arraylist
ArrayList B = new ArrayList(a);
```

`A` and `B` will actually contain the same elements, but `A == B` will return false

Answer (score 1):

`for (ArrayList a : result) temp.add(new ArrayList(a));`

Will add a new `ArrayList` to `temp` that contains the elements of `a`.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29

Adding or deleting stuff in `a`, won't change anything for the list that was added to `temp`.

`for (ArrayList a : result) temp.add(a);`

Will add `a` to `temp`. Due to the same reference, changes of `a` affect the list that was added to `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with a very simple example:

```
final List<String> a = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
System.out.println(a);
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c]
```

Now, lets copy using `=`

```
final List<String> b = a;
b.add("d");
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(a == b);
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c, d]
[a, b, c, d]
true
```

Okay, now lets copy using `new`:

```
final List<String> c = new ArrayList<>(b);
c.add("e");
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(c == b);
```

Output:

```
[a, b, c, d, e]
[a, b, c, d]
[a, b, c, d]
false
```

Okay, so when we copy using `=` we **copy the reference** to the **same `List`**. When we copy using the copy constructor we actually create an **entirely separate `List`** that contains the same elements.

So `a` and `b` are **references** to some same list, they will always return the same result, and any action on `a` will affect `b` - think of them as aliases for some other entity.

`c` is a physical copy of `a` (and `b` for that matter) where we have constructed a `new` entity and copied the contents of `a` into it.

So, to answer your question; your first method copies **the references** and your second method copies **the contents**.

Answer (score 0):

This is adding a new Arraylist with item of a in temp while iterating result arraylist

```
 for (ArrayList a : result)
 temp.add(new ArrayList(a));
```

This is adding a in temp while iterating result arraylist

```
    for (ArrayList a : result)
 temp.add(a);
```